# App crashes when closed while using a service android, as im trying to use intents

Tags: android, android-intent, service

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        String temp = intent.getStringExtra("key");
        temp1 = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        counter = temp1;
    }
}
```

I'm passing data to the service and it works perfectly when the app is open but crashes as soon as i close the app.. I've tried a lot of things and I'm new to android. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Here is the log

```
03-21 15:35:07.868 21818-21818/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.cs442.shash5259.assignment_6, PID: 21818
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.cs442.shash5259.assignment_6.Myservice@9d88461 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1452)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.cs442.shash5259.assignment_6.Myservice.onStartCommand(Myservice.java:55)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3028)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1452) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: Please post more details. What is the logcat when app crashes?

Comment: 03-21 15:35:07.868 21818-21818/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.cs442.shash5259.assignment_6, PID: 21818
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.cs442.shash5259.assignment_6.Myservice@9d88461 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

Comment: that happens only when i close my app else it works

Comment: i believe the issue is that your intent is null

Comment: @RusheelJain  yea im passing the intent from my main activity to this class

Comment: Yes but given your error log, error seems to occur at intent.getExtra()

My guess is that your service is called again when you close the app, at that time there is no intent being passed (Adnroid framework makes this call?), which means intent is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the logs, it is clear that your Intent object in `onStartCommand` is `null`, when app is closed.

Looking at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) inside the source code of Service, it is mentioned that:

> The `Intent` supplied to `onStartCommand`  may be null if the service
>   is being restarted after
>        its process has gone away, and it had previously returned anything
>         except `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY`.

You can deal with this in at least 2 different ways depending on your app's requirement.

1.You can modify the code as below in your onStartCommand:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent!= null) {
            String temp = intent.getStringExtra("key");
            temp1 = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            counter = temp1;
        }
    }
```

This will prevent the crash but will not update the `counter`

2.Or you may return `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` in the `onStartCommand()` callback in  service  so that the entire intent is sent following a restart, thus preventing `Intent` from being `null`.

Comment: thanks that solved it START_REDELIVER_INTENT did the trick although it takes quite awhile for the app to restart

Comment: Thanks. Saved my day